# Scrolling issues using RadioGroup in Listview?

Tags: android

In My activity which contain on List view. Listview row contain one Textview and three Radiobutton in RadioGroup. when i select first radiobutton in first row after scrolling listView after ten (10) row the first radiobutton automatically selected appear.this will happen after every ten(10) row i don't know how?

**CustomAdapter class**

```
public class StudentAttendanceCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<StudentDataReader> studentRecord;
    private List<StudentDataReader> mOriginalValues;
    public HashMap<String, String> radioMap;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1, radioButtonId;

    public StudentAttendanceCustomAdapter(TeacherAttendanceActivity activity, List<StudentDataReader> studentList) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.studentRecord = studentList;
        this.mOriginalValues = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return studentRecord.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return studentRecord.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView studentName;
        RadioButton rb_p;
        RadioButton rb_a;
        RadioButton rb_l;
        RadioGroup rg;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder hoder = new ViewHolder();
        if (inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_attendance_row,parent,false);

            hoder.studentName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendance_studentName);
            hoder.rg = (RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rg_1);
            hoder.rb_p = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_present);
            hoder.rb_a = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_absent);
            hoder.rb_l = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_leave);
            convertView.setTag(hoder);
        }else {
            hoder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final String str_studentId,str_studentName;
        final StudentDataReader s = studentRecord.get(position);
        hoder.studentName.setText(s.getStudentName());
        str_studentId= s.getStudentId();
        str_studentName = s.getStudentName();


        hoder.rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int childCount = group.getChildCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i);

                    if (radioButton.getId() == checkedId) {
                        s.setPresent(radioButton.getText().toString());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

please any one help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35862385/2128166 
it has different data but you can take reference of how you can hold state of radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Your view holder will keep view state. For each item you have to keep data by and array in adapter or put to item object data.

Comment: thank for replay but i don't know how to implement it. please help me

Comment: supposing, an item shows YourData object. I can add to this object a property called selectedRadioPosition, when user click on radio, get this position and set to selectedRadioPosition. In get view. check postion and setchecked for radiobutton on this position

Comment: Please if possible then tell me where i can update my java code and how because i don't know what type of you ask to change please please

Comment: Add to StudentDataReader a int properties called mSelectedRadio

Comment: ok i added like this  studentDataReder.setPosition(mSelectedPosition); next

Comment: On getView method in Adapter. get this selectedposition a set for radiobutton